# syntax error redirects to a 'Server not found' page

Tags: php, cakephp, syntax, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to access an element of an array in PHP using the following method:

```
$test = $this->Student->find('first',array('conditions',array('Student.student_table_id'=>1)))['Student']['student_id'];
```

It seems to work well on a slightly newer version of XAMPP, but when I try to use that syntax on another machine with an older version of XAMPP for Mac OS X 1.7.3 installation, it throws me to a `Server not found` page. I don't know if it something to do with my XAMPP configuration or something else..

Also, this behavior, i.e. redirection to a server not found page, happens whenever there is a syntax error.

Mind you, both machines support the minimum requirements of CakePHP.

Comment: the PHP Version on the problematic machine is 5.3.1
While on the other machine is 5.5.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comment..

> the PHP Version on the problematic machine is 5.3.1

That is because you are trying to use a [**new feature**](https://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) of PHP 5.4 , called the *function array dereferencing*.

#### How to fix ?

Break down your code like this.

```
$test  = $this->Student->find('first',array('conditions',array('Student.student_table_id'=>1)));
$test1 = $test['Student']['student_id'];
```

Comment: alright, thanks man. I will upgrade my php version. I will tick the answer correct in a while once I update

Comment: Yeah the better way will be upgrading instead of doing this fix.